# Json deserialization issue in spring 3.2.0

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a problem while deserializing array of objects using Spring 3.2.0 and Jackson 2.1.1. 
When i hit a controller with array of objects it throws **"Could not instantiate bean class. No default Constructor found"**. My Pojo has default constructor also. I'm using *MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter* in dispatcher-servlet for JSON processing.

Pojo:

```
  public class Student{

    private String rollNum;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

            public Student(){

            }

    /**
     * @return the firstName
     */
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    /**
     * @param firstName the firstName to set
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the lastName
     */
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    /**
     * @param lastName the lastName to set
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the rollNum
     */
    public String getRollNum() {
        return rollNum;
    }
    /**
     * @param rollNum the rollNum to set
     */
    public void setRollNum(String rollNum) {
        this.rollNum = rollNum;
    }
}
```

Controller Class:

```
public @ResponseBody
String saveStudentName(
        final @ModelAttribute Student[] student){

      //code goes here

  }
```

This service is hit by an iOS application. When i hit the same service with single object(@ModelAttribute Student student), it works fine. But hitting with array of objects, it throws exception as

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [[Lcom.student.pojo.Student;]: No default constructor found;
```

Client side input is

```
[{"rollNum":"12","firstName":"qweqw","lastName":"adsf"},{"rollNum":"23","firstName":"rty","lastName":"fghj"}]
```

and client gets the below error as response

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x7522680 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
```

Please some one tell where i'm wrong. If controller parameter is correct, please tell the input format which i can send to controller.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you try accepting List<Student> in service class instead of Student[].

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a wrapper around the list of Student like this:

```
  class Students extends ArrayList<Student> {
     public Students() {
       super();
     }
  }
```

Also change the service method like this:

```
  public @ResponseBody String saveStudentName(final @ModelAttribute Students students){

      //code goes here

  }
```

I guess this will resolve your issue .

~Ragesh AK

Comment: Thanks Ragesh. I implemented as per your suggestion. But server received the request as 
    {"rollNum":"3,4" ,"firstName":"asd,asd" ,"lastName":"asas,sdasd"}
I need to receive like
[{"rollNum":"3" ,"firstName":"xyz" ,"lastName":"abc"},{"rollNum":"4" ,"firstName":"abc" ,"lastName":"xyz"}]
Please tell how to achieve this.

Comment: I have tried the request from the HTTPRequester-Firefox plugin..and it worked fine for me..Need to set content-type as 'application/json'..Make sure that u r sending the array of objects rather than a single object...Confirm it at the client side.. Try to test the service using the plugin I mentioned above and let me know the result..

Comment: I have tried to hit service using HTTPRequester-Firefox plugin, but controller receives as null values for student object (ex.rollNum=null). Can you tell the input format at client side for sending array of objects?

Comment: I have tried like this in my case: [{"name":"Ragesh","id":"101","address":"kochi"},
{"name":"Ragesh1","id":"1011","address":"kochi1"}]..

Comment: In HTTPRequester-Firefox plugin ,I'm sending the same format and content-type as 'application/json' using POST. But in Server side, I am getting null for all the fields. I am not able to find where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
Below are the complete configs:

**My pom.xml:**


<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.springframework.rest</groupId>
  <artifactId>RestWebService</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>RestWebService Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <!--  Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.7</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <!-- dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-stream</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>RestWebService</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>  
</project>

**dispatcher-servlet.xml:**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springframework.rest" />
    <!-- To enable @RequestMapping process on type level and method level -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>              
                <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
    </bean> 
</beans>


**Student:**

public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private String address;


    public Student() {

    }

    public Student(int id, String name, String address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }



}

**Students:**

public class Students extends ArrayList<Student> {

    public Students() {
        super();
    }

}

**Controller:**

@Controller
public class BaseController{    

    @RequestMapping(value="/student", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String saveStudent(@RequestBody Students students) {
        System.out.println("Size:"+students.size());
        return "Success";
    }

}
```

Please let me know if this helps you ....

Comment: Thanks Ragesh. I have the configuration like you posted. When i send a json request like {"rollNum":"12","firstName":"abc","lastName":"pqr"}, controller does not map and assigns null to all fields in pojo. But when i send request like "rollNum=12&firstName=abc&lastName=pqr" it maps to pojo fields. Please suggest where can i configure anything to map json request?

Comment: Thank you Ragesh. I implemented the controller with @RequestBody and receiving as array of objects(Student[] student), it works fine.